# How to prevent iframe to reload when moving it to a different parent with appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to move an iframe to a different parent element keeping the iframe state (preserving the scroll position and any information that may have been entered to a form, etc.)

When the iframe element is moved using `appendChild()` it is also reloaded which resets the state. Is it possible to prevent that?

I have created a live example to show that. https://jsbin.com/kejoweniva/edit?output

Open the example, scroll and then click the button, the iframe is reloaded automatically when appended to a new parent.

html

```
  <div class="target"></div>
  <iframe src="https://2017.cssconf.eu/"></iframe>
  <button onclick="moveIframe()">move iframe</button>
```

javascript

```
function moveIframe() {
  console.log('moving iframe')
  var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]
  document.getElementsByClassName('target')[0].appendChild(iframe)
}
```

Comment: It isn't possible to move an iframe from one place in the dom to another without it reloading.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't possible to move an iframe from one place in the dom to another without it reloading.
Its a bug lies to browsers in how they interpret event when you attempt to move the iframe using methods such as `appendChild()` or `insertBefore()`.

You can use css Workarounds if you just need to move the IFrame on the page. 
Here is a [JsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tnmahdi/v2p8213r/7/) based on your work.

Comment: I need the parent element of the iframe to change in my case

Comment: I'm sorry but moving the IFrame SOM location will cause the reload of content.